# Given $u=f(x,y)$ & $v=g(x,y)$, express the area element $dA=dxdy$ in terms of $u,v,du$ & $dv$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, partial-derivative, jacobian

[image]

Possible solution:-

$\begin{aligned}& h(x, y)=(f(x, y), g(x, y)) \\ & J(h(x, y))=\left|\begin{array}{cc}f_{x} & f_{y} \\ g_{x} & g_{y}\end{array}\right|=\left(f_{x} g_{y}-f_{y} g_{x}\right) \end{aligned}$

$A=|J|^{-1}dudv$
$=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)^{-1}$ $dudv$

I think the key idea is to use the Jacobian but this gives me an expression with x and y as I apply the chain rule. Is this still the right answer? [Standard notation for partial derivatives used]

Edit: Addressed in comments

Comment: It will be $\frac{1}{|J|}$, since $u_x v_y - u_y v_x$ is the determinant of the inverse Jacobian matrix.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Forgot the ^(-1). Will add it